# Select query only when a value is not null in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    @EnrollmentTime = T1.EnrollmentTime 
FROM 
    T1 
INNER JOIN 
    T2 ON T1.DeviceMacAddress = T2.DeviceMacAddress 
WHERE 
    T1.ID = @LocationID
```

I want to select this query only when this scenario exists else select 
something.

How to achieve this with minimal lines of code

Comment: what scenario exists?  join or where clause

Comment: if @EnrollmentTime is not null then only this must be returned from stored procedure

Comment: and if it is null then ?

Comment: if `@EnrollmentTime` is not null or is null ??

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use `ISNULL` as below

```
SELECT @EnrollmentTime=ISNULL(@EnrollmentTime, T1.EnrollmentTime) 
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2  ON T1.DeviceMacAddress=T2.DeviceMacAddress 
WHERE T1.ID=@LocationID
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
  IF (@EnrollmentTime IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@EnrollmentTime) > 0)
            SELECT @EnrollmentTime=T1.EnrollmentTime 
            FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2  ON T1.DeviceMacAddress=T2.DeviceMacAddress WHERE 
            T1.ID=@LocationID
    ELSE
            PRINT 'else';
```